# .composer is full ? No space left on device

Tags: symfony, composer-php, capistrano

When I deploy my project with capistrano (for Symfony), I have this error :

```
INFO [72050b7f] Running /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader as dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DEBUG [72050b7f] Command: cd /var/www/dev/Dome/releases/20160812073355 && ( export SYMFONY_ENV="prod" ; /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader )
DEBUG [72050b7f]    The disk hosting /var/www/.composer is full, this may be the cause of the following exception
DEBUG [72050b7f]
DEBUG [72050b7f]
[ErrorException]
ZipArchive::extractTo(): No space left on device
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could it be that there is no space left on the device...?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What kind of environment are you running this on? Is this your local computer, a VM, a CI machine, a Docker container?

Comment: **BEWARE:** in my case the message was misleading! The actual problem was the user that was attempting to exec the instructions. Using the `root` user it didn't have any space-left issue! Not sure if it is some issue with quotas.

Answer (score 6):

Just clear cache of composer use `composer clear-cache`
[Reference](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md)

Answer (score 3):

Use `df -h` to check all partitions (make sure to check the relevant partition, there can be multiple) and free space if possible.

Alternative options;

- You can try changing the Composer home directory to another partition/location using the environment variable `COMPOSER_HOME=/new/path`.
- You can disable the cache directory by using `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

`The disk hosting /var/www/.composer is full`.

The message is quite expressive, you have run out of ROM memory on your disk / partition, and can no longer download even source-code packages with composer.

I suggest you to either change of disk, or if it is a virtual partition, to improve the memory-size.

This does not seem to be related with either Capistrano, Symfony, Composer or PHP.

Comment: Thanks I'm newbie in server. But, when I use the commands (df or df -i), my device is not full :/

Comment: is there a quota that limits your usable space?

Comment: What exactly does the `df -h /var/www` command returns ?
What about `cd /var/www && du -h -c -s` ?

Answer (score -1):

You have no permission to run the commands, if it works with sudo you did your deploy with root privilegies in the first place.

Comment: This has no link with the stated issue or at least elaborate on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).